# Как обвернуть OpenGL на С++ в GNU/Linux

Tags: c++, linux, ооп, функции, opengl

Что я делаю не так, это очень примитивный вопрос, который  вы слышите уже не первый раз. А я хочу спросить, как исправить ошибки в коде, чтобы всё работало.
Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

//#include "2dRender/2drender.h"


class Main{
public:
std::vector <float> vertexsi[1][3]={};
std::vector <float>  normalsi;
std::vector <float> texturesi;
std::vector <float> colorsi;
std::vector <float> indexsi;

virtual void draw2(){
 void draw2D();
}
virtual void draw3(){
void draw3D();

}
 static void main(){
extern int main();
}
};
Main::draw2D(){
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
glClearDepth(0.0);
glOrtho(0.0,windowsW,windowsH,0.0,0.0,1.0);
gluOrtho2D(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0); 
glPointSize(1);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,&vertexsi);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,3);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);


glEnableClientState(GL_INDEX_ARRAY);
glIndexPointer(GL_FLOAT,0,&indexsi);
glDisableClientState(GL_INDEX_ARRAY);

glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glColorPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,&colorsi);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glTexCoordPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,&texturesi);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

glDisable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glutSwapBuffers();
return Main;
}

int main(int argcp,char** argv){

Main n;

glutInit(&argcp,argv);
glutInitWindowSize(600,800/*windowsW,windowsH*/);
glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
glutCreateWindow("test");
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA| GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_DEPTH);
glutDisplayFunc(draw2D);
glutMainLoop();
//std::vector <float> vertexsi[1][3]={};

return 0;
}
```

Вот ошибки:

```
main/main.cpp:44:14: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘draw2D’ with no type [-fpermissive]
 Main::draw2D(){
              ^
main/main.cpp:44:14: error: no ‘int Main::draw2D()’ member function declared in class ‘Main’
```

Comment: `Main::draw2D` -> `void Main::draw2D`. Компилятор ведь даже подсказал, что типа не хватает.

Comment: я так пробовал. main/main.cpp:44:19: error: no ‘void Main::draw2D()’ member function declared in class ‘Main’
 void Main::draw2D(){

Comment: Надо было мне сначала на код нормально посмотреть, а потом писать. Что по вашему делает эта функция: `virtual void draw2(){void draw2D();}`? Аналогично `draw3` и `main` (первый из двух).

Comment: Пора перечитывать "Специальное издание Бьерна Страуструпа"... Методы класса, вызывать рендеринг функции из метода функции.

Comment: Угу, надо перечитывать. `void draw2D();` - это объявление функции, а не вызов...

Comment: вызыв функции из функции рендеринга opengl 
glutDisplayFunc(draw2D);